# How can I Render A Dynamically Created PDF file on UI <Iframe> or <DIV>

Tags: javascript, java, user-interface, pdf, iframe

I am using the below code , But this one is automatically download the PDF file on my local machine. I don,t want to download this by default. I want to show the pdf file on UI  or .

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + reportFileName + ".pdf\"");
            response.setContentType(reportType.getContentType());

```
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());

        LavanteReportFooter event = new LavanteReportFooter();
        writer.setPageEvent(event);         
        document.open();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(reportColumnHeaders.size());
        table.setWidthPercentage(100); //Width 100%
        table.setSpacingBefore(10f); //Space before table
        table.setSpacingAfter(10f); //Space after table

        Font pdfTitleFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA);
        pdfTitleFont.setSize(12f);
        pdfTitleFont.setStyle(Font.BOLD);

        Paragraph pdfTitle = new Paragraph(reportFileName, pdfTitleFont);
        pdfTitle.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

        PdfPCell pdfTitleCell = new PdfPCell(pdfTitle);
        pdfTitleCell.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        pdfTitleCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        pdfTitleCell.setColspan(reportColumnHeaders.size());
        pdfTitleCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

        table.addCell(pdfTitleCell);

        PdfPCell blankCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(""));
        blankCell.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        blankCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        blankCell.setColspan(reportColumnHeaders.size());
        blankCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

        table.addCell(blankCell);
        table.addCell(blankCell);

        Font headerFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA);
        headerFont.setSize(9f);

        for (String reportColumnHeader : reportColumnHeaders) {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(reportColumnHeader, headerFont));
            cell.setPadding(4);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            cell.setBorderWidth(0.5f);
            cell.setBorderColor(new Color(173, 173, 172));
            cell.setBackgroundColor(new Color(247, 247, 253));
            table.addCell(cell);
        }

        Font dateFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA);
        dateFont.setSize(8f);

        table.setSplitRows(false);
        table.setComplete(false);

        int rowNum = 1;
        Iterator<List<String>> iterator = dataRows.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            if(rowNum % 200 == 0){
                document.add(table);
            }

            List<java.lang.String> row = (List<java.lang.String>) iterator.next();
            for (String column : row) {
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(column, dateFont));
                if(rowNum % 2 == 0){
                    cell.setBackgroundColor(new Color(247, 247, 253));
                }else{
                    cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                cell.setPadding(4f);
                cell.setBorderWidth(0.5f);
                cell.setBorderColor(new Color(173, 173, 172));
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                table.addCell(cell);
            }
            row.clear();
            iterator.remove();
            rowNum = rowNum +1;
        }

        table.setComplete(true);
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
        writer.close();
    }
```

Comment: The code dump in question has zero relevance to what you are actually asking. The code generates a new pdf file, but you are asking for a way to display pdf content on a web page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)